# Calling a templated base class method compile fails

Tags: c++, templates

I am attempting to call a templated base class method through a derived class.
This is my code

```
struct base
{
    template<typename t>
    void baseMethod(t s)
    {
        std::cout << s;
    }
};


struct der : public base
{
};


int main()
{
  der d;
  d.<int>(baseMethod(12));
}
```

The compilation fails and states

> main.cpp: In function 'int main()': main.cpp:25:5: error: expected
>   unqualified-id before '<' token    d.(baseMethod(12));
>        ^ main.cpp:25:6: error: expected primary-expression before 'int'    d.(baseMethod(12));

Any suggestions on how I can fix it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notwithstanding the fact that this questuion has nothing to do with the inheritance, the proper syntax would be

```
d.baseMethod<int>(12);
```

However, even this is not needed due to [template deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction): simple

```
d.baseMethod(12);
```

would work.

Comment: Thanks. The syntax threw me of - MArked as the answer after timer